# Radcombo box disappears after insert?

Tags: telerik, radgrid

I am developing a radgrid that can be used as a form.

One of the columns uses a RadComboBox within a GridTemplate Column.

My problem is that after the user clicks on the Insert button, the page refreshes but the user's choice from the radcomboBox is gone:

[image: The 3 rows below the drop down should show what the user selected]

[image]

Here is my aspx code for the template column

```
<telerik:GridTemplateColumn UniqueName="UserCol" HeaderText="Employee" DataField="UserID">

                           <EditItemTemplate>
                               <telerik:RadComboBox ID="RadComboBox1" runat="server" AutoPostBack="false" CausesValidation="true"
                                            Width="240" MaxHeight="200px" OnItemsRequested="ddEmployee_ItemsRequested" AllowCustomText="true"
                                            EnableLoadOnDemand="true" ShowMoreResultsBox="true" EnableVirtualScrolling="true"
                                            MarkFirstMatch="false" >
                                </telerik:RadComboBox>
                           </EditItemTemplate>
                       </telerik:GridTemplateColumn>
```

How can I ensure that the user's choice from the RadComboBox is still visible?

Comment: Once you click on the `Add new` button, the contents of `<InsertItemTemplate>` are being displayed. This contains a different server side control than the `RadComboBox` of `<EditItemTemplate>`.

Comment: Could you please also add RadComBox inside ItemTemplate?